# store multi-choice-quiz in sql database with variable answer count

Tags: sql

My assignment about "Survey website" required function that allow user create questions for survey. I want count of ansers per question is variable. If i store my question in XML file, that requirement seem to rather easy. But now I not yet found best way to design "Question" table in SQL database.

In xml, question structure concept like this, remember this is just like-xml describer.

How the best way to my question can store variable answer-count?

```
<Questions>
    <Question ID="identity: string" difficult="point: int">
        <Content>
            <!-- Question's content -->
        </Content>

        <Answer isRight="true">
            <!-- this is an right choise -->
        </Answer>

        <Answer>
            <!-- another choise -->
        </Answer>

        <Answer isRight="true">
            <!-- another choise -->
        </Answer>

        <Answer>
            <!-- another choise -->
        </Answer>
    </Question>

    <!-- ............ -->
    <Question></Question>
    <Question></Question>

</Questions>

<Surveys>
    <survey ID="identity: string">
        <name></name>
                    <questionID="" />
                    <questionID="" />
                    <questionID="" />
    </survey>

    <!-- có nhiều survey -->
    <survey></survey>
    <survey></survey>
</Surveys>
```

Comment: create three tables: survey, question, answers.  Link by PK/FK relationships.

Comment: The choices for the answers is just multiple choices with one or more right answer?

Comment: @jorge: yes, multi choice only.

Comment: @OldProgramer: Because each "Answer" too litle, but total count of them too many, so I want to consult other way before, if no way I will implement your instruct, thanks you.

Comment: So **best** choice would be that one suggested by @OldProgrammer. And if you want to keep it scalable, think about put some more, like answer_type ( like multiple choice, describable ) and another one to store the answers for specific types.

Comment: okay, i am no more wonder, thanks to your help.

Comment: OK, sorry, but I don't understand your comments to well.  Good luck.  read up on database design and normalization.